# iOS App's Documents directory contents lost after Restore from Backup

Tags: ios, itunes, nsdocumentdirectory

I am working on an App that requires a folder structure in the Documents directory to access images and videos in various modules. These are stored there using a download process and it works fine.

While testing I restored the app using iTunes. I found that none of the downloaded assets where visible. After some searching I used the Download Container option in the Devices window of Xcode to view the package contents of my App.I found that all files that where stored in the documents directory were present, but none of the folders were present. I think this is what causes the issue.

I tried another similar project, but the folder structure was intact.

Comment: What do you mean by "restored the app using iTunes"? Does your folder get disappeared and files remains there?

Comment: I connected the iPad to my Mac, then used Restore Backup option under Manually BackUp and Restore. Yes. I store some images taken by the user directly under the documents  folder.They are still there. So are some DB files that I create programatically. But there is a folder structure that i create when the user opens the app for the first time.That has gone missing